# Is the minus absolute value of the difference a kernel?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Precisely, is $k(x_i- x_j) = -\|x_i-x_j\| \quad x_i, x_j \in \mathbb R$ a valid kernel?

I know that the absolute value of kernel formulation is not a valid kernel since it is not positive semi-definite. However, the above-mentioned kernel in the literature is referred to as an energy kernel and it is used to calculate energy distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance

[https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~wahba/stat860public/pdf4/Energy/EnergyDistance10.1002-wics.1375.pdf](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Ewahba/stat860public/pdf4/Energy/EnergyDistance10.1002-wics.1375.pdf)

In brief, is it a kernel ($k$), if not why it is referred to as an energy kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different authors use the term "kernel" differently. In the machine learning community, some similarity measures are called kernels, such as
$$k(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
1 , \text{ if } \|x-y\| \le \epsilon \\
0 , \text{ else}
\end{cases}$$
that is popular in spectral graph clustering. However, by choosing a data set $\cal X = \{0,1,2\}$ and $ \epsilon = 1$, you end up with a kernel matrix that has negative eigenvalues, so this kernel is not PSD.

On the other hand, mathematics tend to use kernels as a synonym for PSD kernels. Mercer's theorem guarantees that then, and only then, does there exist a Hilbert space $\cal H$ in which the inner product is described by $k$, in the sense that there exist map $\phi$ such that
$$\forall x,y \in \cal X: \langle \phi(x) , \phi(y) \rangle_\cal H = k(x,y)$$

Now to your kernel: It is not PSD. Take $\cal X = \{0,1\}$ and check the resulting kernel matrix.